# Pulling token from JSON responce in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, post, python-2.x

I am learning Python and am working with the API for MediaFire and trying to just automate some simple processes. But I am running into a bit of confusion after I pass the POST to get the Session Token. The problem is that I am not sure how to extract the token from the response. Here is the call to get the session token:

```
import hashlib
import time
import urllib.request

token = hashlib.sha1()
token.update("calvinrock0406@gmail.comheaven3610255k592k2di4u9uok3e8u9pkfepjfoc809kfutv5z".encode('utf-8'))
token_dig = token.hexdigest()

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.mediafire.com/api/user/get_session_token.php?application_id=36102&signature=" + token_dig + "&email=calvinrock0406@gmail.com&password=heaven&token_version=2&response_format=json") as response:
    html = response.read()
```

And here is the responce I get back from the call:

```
b'{"response":{"action":"user\\/get_session_token","session_token":"618679cd5046c48fface93dee366a1a07eacfefc5bce88173d5118bb3f128f539602dc54f6d667825a376bc2f86b41a5b1cbe178cd45dfcb4ddfc8e9652f7c529db233181655ec42","secret_key":"774329384","time":"1454700043.4884","ekey":"a84adbba31f9ae8ef717486616a97c63","pkey":"b4dfdc307d","result":"Success","current_api_version":"1.5"}}'
```

Any help for the noob would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using [**`requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead of **`urllib`**, and use **`json()`** to work with the response:

```
import json
import hashlib
import requests

token = hashlib.sha1()
token.update("calvinrock0406@gmail.comheaven3610255k592k2di4u9uok3e8u9pkfepjfoc809kfutv5z".encode('utf-8'))
token_dig = token.hexdigest()

response = requests.get("https://www.mediafire.com/api/user/get_session_token.php?application_id=36102&signature=" + token_dig + "&email=calvinrock0406@gmail.com&password=heaven&token_version=2&response_format=json")

json_response = response.json()
print json_response["response"]["session_token"]
```

Comment: I put it and gave it a test run and ran into an error, do I need to set a argument to convert to a string?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rhood\Documents\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    json_response = json.loads(html)
  File "C:\Users\rhood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: loads takes a string as an input

Comment: You can simplify further by using `response.json()` instead of `json.loads(response.text)`